# unit test for proxy checking

Tags: python, unit-testing, proxy

Proxy configuration of a machine can be easily fetched using

```
def check_proxy():    
     import urllib2
     http_proxy = urllib2.getproxies().get('http')
```

I need to write a test for the above written function. In order to do that I need to:-

1. Set the system-wide proxy to an
   invalid URL during the test(sounds 
   like a bad idea).
2. Supply an invalid
       URL to http_proxy.

How can I achieve either of the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the question tags I see you want to write *unit-tests* for the function. And where is *your* unit here? Where is *your* business logic? `getproxies` and `get` are functions of the standard Python library. You shouldn't test others' code in your unit-tests. Furthermore it enough to test only [Things That Could Possibly Break](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestEverythingThatCouldPossiblyBreak).

If I've misunderstood your question and indeed your function looks like this:

```
def check_proxy():    
     import urllib
     http_proxy = urllib.getproxies().get('http')
     # some “complex” code that uses http_proxy
```

and you don't know how to test the “complex” code due to dependency on proxy, I recommend to split the function in two:

```
def check_proxy():    
     import urllib
     http_proxy = urllib.getproxies().get('http')
     _check_proxy(http_proxy)

def _check_proxy(http_proxy):
     # some “complex” code that uses http_proxy
```

Now you're able to test `_check_proxy` alone, using any mock/stub you specially prepared for the role of `http_proxy`. Write few tests for `_check_proxy` and leave original `check_proxy` untested (in sense of *unit*-tests). It is OK.

Answer (score 1):

The exact behaviour of getproxies varies according the the system you're on, but I believe that in all cases it looks first in the environment then checks the system specific place for proxy settings (such as the registry on windows).

So try:

```
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'whatever invalid URL you want'
```